# sequence and cakes

Tags: real-analysis

A whole cake is 1.

Now I cut a slice of cake taking off a portion of $p<1$ and then another slice of cake taking off a portion p from what remains from the previous operation. I repeat this an indefinite number of times.
How much cake remains at last?

My solution is:
$$(1-p)-(1-p)p-(1-p)p*p-...=(1-p)(2-(p^0+p^1+p^2+...))=(1-p)(2- \frac{1}{1-p})=1-2p$$   but the solution suggested in my book is 0.
Why?

Comment: Well, say $T_n$ is the amount you have after $n$ cuts have been removed.  Thus $T_0=1$ and $T_n=T_{n-1}-pT_{n-1}=(1-p)T_{n-1}$.  It follows that $T_n=(1-p)^n$.  Can you finish?

Comment: @lulu ahhh ok thanks for your help

Comment: Do you see the error in your calculation?  Write it out in stages.  You correctly get $T_1=(1-p)$ and $T_2=(1-p)^2$.  However the next term you subtract is not correct.